# Place item in ActionBar at a specific position

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I would like to place an `item` in the `ActionBar` just before the app icon as shown in the following figure. The icon/item when clicked will display a fragment as shown in the second image.

[image]

[image]

But I couldn't find any way how place items in the ActionBar at specific locations.
Any suggestions how this can be done.

The screenshots are from the Android app for [flipkart](http://www.flipkart.com) found [here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.flipkart.android).

Thanks

Comment: do u really mean a navigation drawer

Comment: @Ansar: I didn't knew if something like Navigation Drawer existed. Thanks, that helped.